# Render CoreGraphics to OpenGL texture on IOS

Tags: ios, pdf, core-graphics, opengl-es-2.0

Using `CoreGraphics` on iOS is very easy to use, but it is possible to get the output of `CoreGraphics` and put it into `OpenGL` Textures?

The final goal is to use `CGContextDrawPDFPage` to render very performant pdf's and write it into a specific texture id with

```
OpenGL.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TextureNativeId);
```

It does look like `CoreGraphics` is not able to render directly into a specific "native texture id".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, by rendering your Core Graphics content to a bitmap context and uploading that to a texture. The following is code that I use to draw a UIImage to a Core Graphics context, but you could replace the `CGContextDrawImage()` portion with your own drawing code:

```
GLubyte *imageData = (GLubyte *) calloc(1, (int)pixelSizeOfImage.width * (int)pixelSizeOfImage.height * 4);
CGColorSpaceRef genericRGBColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();    
CGContextRef imageContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(imageData, (int)pixelSizeOfImage.width, (int)pixelSizeOfImage.height, 8, (int)pixelSizeOfImage.width * 4, genericRGBColorspace,  kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
CGContextDrawImage(imageContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, pixelSizeOfImage.width, pixelSizeOfImage.height), [newImageSource CGImage]);
CGContextRelease(imageContext);
CGColorSpaceRelease(genericRGBColorspace);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, outputTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, (int)pixelSizeOfImage.width, (int)pixelSizeOfImage.height, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
```

This assumes that you've created your texture using code like the following:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glGenTextures(1, &outputTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, outputTexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
// This is necessary for non-power-of-two textures
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

For rapidly changing content, you might want to look into iOS 5.0's texture caches (`CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage()` and the like), which might let you render directly to the bytes for your texture. However, I've found that the overhead for creating and rendering to a texture with a texture cache makes this slightly slower for rendering a single image, so if you don't need to continually update this the code above is probably your fastest route.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, create a texture for OpenGL using Core Graphics.  However, when I provide my drawing code such as `context.fill(rect1)`, I get a BAD_ACCESS fault.  I'm currently trying to create the texture from prepareOpenGL(), but I've tried drawRect(_:) and got the same result. It seems you are both creating a CGContext in an NSOpenGLView, yes? Any thoughts?