# Why am I getting a BAD_ACCESS fault when calling draw functions on a CGContext used for an OpenGL texture?

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics, exc-bad-access, opengl-3

I am trying to create an OpenGL texture using Core Graphics.  My code setup is in `prepareOpenGL()`.  While drawing to the initialized `CGContext`, I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` fault.  However, when I po the context in LLDB (`po context!`, see below), I get an address with all of the CGContext's information.  I have tried calling an expression through LLDB as well, and the output is `nil`.  Address sanitizer, thread sanitizer, and zombies were non-revealing.  My question is why is the CGContext being stated as nil, `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, when the `Optional<CGContext>` is not `nil`?  I have tried calling this code in `drawRect(_:)`, but I get the same results.

```swift
import Cocoa
import CoreGraphics
import OpenGL.GL3

class MyView: NSOpenGLView {
    var textureTBO: GLuint = 0

    override func prepareOpenGL() {
        let bitmapRows = 10
        let bitmapColumns = 10
        let floatsPerPoint = 4
        var bitmapBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CGFloat>.allocate(capacity: bitmapRows * bitmapColumns * floatsPerPoint)

        if let context = CGContext(data: &bitmapBuffer,
                                width: bitmapColumns,
                                height: bitmapRows,
                                bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                bytesPerRow: bitmapColumns * floatsPerPixel,
                                space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                                bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipLast.rawValue) {
            context.setFillColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5)
            context.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 5, height: 5))       //=>  EXC_BAD_ACCESS, code=2
            context.setFillColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5)
            context.fill(CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: 5, height: 5))
            context.setFillColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
            context.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 5, width: 5, height: 5))
            context.setFillColor(red: 0.5, green: 0, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
            context.fill(CGRect(x: 5, y: 0, width: 5, height: 5))
        
            glGenTextures(1, &textureTBO)
            glBindTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), textureTBO)
            glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER), GL_LINEAR)
            glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER), GL_LINEAR)
            glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S), GL_REPEAT)
            glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T), GL_REPEAT)
        }

        glTexImage2D(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), 0, GLint(GL_RGB), 256, 256, 0, GLenum(GL_RGBA), GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_INT), &bitmapBuffer)

        bitmapBuffer.deallocate()
    }
}
```

LLDB output - the optional is not nil

```
(lldb) po context!
<CGContext 0x7b3000000300> (kCGContextTypeBitmap)
    <<CGColorSpace 0x7b1800002280> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceRGB)>
        width = 256, height = 256, bpc = 8, bpp = 32, row bytes = 2048 
        kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast | 0 (default byte order)
```

LLDB output - is this telling me that a color cannot be set because the context actually is nil?

```
(lldb) expression context?.setFillColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5)
(Void?) $R4 = nil
```

LLDB output - an exercise in futility:  doing the same thing and expecting a different result, haha

```
(lldb) expression context?.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 5, height: 5))
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7b08000c7ff0).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

It seems that this can be done as I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9909716/3928158).  I appreciate your thoughts, thank you!

Comment: Semi-related but important: if you find yourself using `?.` on the same variable more than 2 or 3 times, you should probably just unwrap the variable once and work with a non-optional from then on. Usually that happens with people doing `self.foo = initialValue()`, then using `self.foo` which has an optional type, even if `initialValue()` always returns a non-optional. Instead it's better to use a local `foo`, and assign it to `self.foo` once you're done manipulating it.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, you are right.  Please forgive my laziness.  I only use the buffer once so I have added an `if let` to the question instead of a local var.  Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: The numbers don't add up: A buffer of `CGFloat`s, `bitsPerComponent: 8`and `bytesPerRow: bitmapColumns * floatsPerPixel * 2`? The biggest issue is `data: &bitmapBuffer`, this is a pointer to the pointer to the buffer. Replace it with `data: bitmapBuffer`.

Comment: @Willeke, removing the `&` does fix the problem, thank you!  I thought I had tried that, but obviously not.  If write up an answer, I'll give you the credit.  I have taken out the extra 2 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data: &bitmapBuffer` is a pointer to the pointer to the buffer. Replace it with `data: bitmapBuffer`.

Not related to the crash but 8 bits per component fits in `UInt8`:

```
var bitmapBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bitmapRows * bitmapColumns * floatsPerPoint)
```